# "runtime 1004: application-defined or object-type defined error" on calculating average of cells

Tags: excel, runtime, vba

I am trying to calculate the average of cells in col b.

The average is calculated by determining the last row with data. e.g. if first row in col B with data is B6 and the last row is B24, then the average is b6:b24 or if last row with data is B8 then average should be for b6:b8.

```
Sub average()
'
' average Macro
'

'
Range("B6").Select

lr = Selection.End(xlDown).Row
fr = lr + 1
r = 6
last = -fr + r

Range("B" & fr & "").Select
activecell.formulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[last]C:R[-1]C)"

End Sub
```

When I run the code, it gives me the error 1004.

I also tried with

```
activecell.formula = "=AVERAGE(R[last]C:R[-1]C)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have either text or data in column B, why not just average the whole column:

```
Application.Worksheetfunction.Average(Activesheet.Range("B:B"))
```

Comment: i want to put the formula in b25 in above case.

Comment: with a little tweak, your solution worked. Thanks a lot. :)
    ActiveCell.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.average(ActiveSheet.Range("B6:B" & fr & ""))

Comment: I'm glad.  You might also look at using a table (XL 2007/10) or List(XL2003, same thing different name), in that range.  It allows your data range to grow or shrink and move the total row accordingly.  Just a guess, but seems like might fit your situation.

Comment: Hello Doug,the above function works in the macro defined in one workbook but does not seem to work in another workbook. Any suggestions?

Comment: lr = Selection.End(xlDown).Row
    fr = lr + 1
    r = 6
    last = -fr + r
    
    Range("B" & fr & "").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveSheet.Range("B6:B" & lr & ""))
    
    Range("C" & fr & "").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range("C6:C" & lr & ""))     '"=SUM(R[-15]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("D" & fr & "").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range("D6:D" & lr & "")) '"=SUM(R[-15]C:R[-1]C)"

Comment: Pretty hard to read that code, but be sure you are qualifying all Range statements, like "ActiveSheet.Range", not just "Range".